# Not getting all the rows in result while using wildcard pattern matching in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database named **student** which has a column named **id** which contains varchar type data as follows:

```
id
050350014831
050350015337
050350015338
050350015339
...
```

I have written the following SQL query to retrieve the id that begins with 05035 using wildcard pattern matching :

```
select id  from student
where id  like '05035%';
```

But I am getting **050350014831** in my output but not getting **050350015337**, **050350015338**, **050350015339** in the result. I am using SQL Server Management Studio. Is there anything wrong in the query?

Comment: Kindly Attach Screen shot form Sql Management studio.

Comment: Please share table structure.

Comment: On the face of it, there's nothing wrong with your query, which suggests there must be something else going on.  Hence the suggestions above to provide more information.

Comment: What happens, if you use condition `where id  like '%05035%'`? There can be some symbol before first visible `0`; of course there can be some invisible symbol inside id also. Or just your table/index is corrupted - use `dbcc checkdb`.

Comment: As already suggested, use other queries to understand the issue better. For example do these return what you expect? `WHERE id = '050350015337'`  and  `WHERE Id LIKE '%337`